# How to install ttf and otf fonts for ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, opentype, truetype

What command do you use to install TrueType fonts or OpenType fonts?
I like ConTeXt and I want to use it with TrueType fonts and OpenType fonts.

There are so many variants of TeX that I don't know. What are you are supposed to do to get fonts working in ConTeXt? Are you supposed to use texfont command:

```
sudo texfont --ve=vendor --co=fontname --en=texnansi
```

Is there an easier way that doesn't require fonts prepared for TeX?
Is this supposed to work

```
mtxrun --script fonts --reload
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply copy the fonts in `$HOME/texmf/fonts/opentype` or `$HOME/texmf/fonts/truetype` and then run

```
mtxrun --script fonts --reload --force
```

Then you can write a typescript to use the font in ConTeXt (depending on the font, ConTeXt might already have a typescript)

Comment: I usually store my fonts in the subtree `/opt/context/tex/texmf-local/fonts` because I like to have everything in one place.

Comment: That's what I do as well. I wanted to write `$TEXMF/fonts/`, but that can be confusing for someone not familiar with TDS. Hence, the simpler answer.

Comment: @Aditya suppose I have my custom fonts stored in `/usr/share/fonts/mycustomfonts`, how can I make ConTeXt see these fonts without having them copied to somewhere else?

Comment: @doctorate You need to set the environment variable `OSFONTDIR`. I usually do `export OSFONTDIR="$HOME/.fonts;/usr/share/fonts;"`